# Native JS in node.js and FRP(bacon.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, frp, bacon.js

I want to use [FRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming) in my project. For node.js I found just one most popular lib, which realize FRP. It's [bacon.js](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/tree/master).
But I don't found exampes of using bacon.js in node.js in native JS (not coffeeScript, not Closure). How can I use 
backon.js in native js in node.js? Or somebody knows a good manual?

Comment: Since coffeescript compiles to js, the api is the same and you can use it in the same way - just with different syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Baconjs](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js) has generated pure js library: https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/tree/master/dist 
For [examples](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/blob/master/examples/examples.html) check this example application - [todoApp](https://github.com/raimohanska/todomvc/blob/bacon-jquery/labs/architecture-examples/baconjs/js/app.js).

Answer (score 3):

The Bacon.js Tutorial Series has Javascript examples. See links on the Bacon.js wiki: https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/wiki/Documentation